# Java Binary Tree, how to implement Node?

Tags: binary-tree, comparable

In the tree class I'm suppose to compare two node, for you know searching and adding items. I have some issues with how to make it comparable. When one adds data(generic, anything) to the tree one calls the Tree class which then makes a new Node object. How can I declare the variable data/element in the Node class so that it is of type E (anything) and still Comparable? Seriously, I've tried back and forth without concluding with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everything is `Comparable`. Your requirement is self-contradictory. You can constrain `E` to be comparable by declaring the generic parameter like:

```
< E extends Comparable<E> >
```

This way, the consumer of the class can use all classes that implement `Comparable` interface with it. You'll be able to access the `compareTo` method on things typed `E`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! No, not everything is. But that would be a requirement of the elements used in the tree. My tiny tree implementation now works and makes sense! Thank you.